# Django 1.6 UpdateView - Have def dispatch() return queryset back

Tags: python, django

In this class based view....assuming that `queryset = self.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)` has a value...I would like it to return it back to `AccountModify` so `def get_object(self, queryset=None):` can take it and return it. Right now `def get_object()` is not receiving it and returning blank `queryset`

```
class AccountCreateOrModify(object):
    model = Employee
    form_class = AccountForm
    template_name = 'bot_data/account_modify.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


class AccountModify(LoginRequiredMixin, 
        AccountCreateOrModify,
        UpdateView):

    def dispatch(self, request,
            *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            pk = self.request.user.pk
            queryset = self.model.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('account_add')

        if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
            handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
        else:
            handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
        return handler(request, queryset)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return queryset
```

Comment: What is self.objects? Do you mean self.model.objects?

Comment: And why do you do the handler stuff? Why not just call the super() class's dispatch method?

Comment: sorry, I fixed the self.model.objects typo. How would I call the super() class's dispatch method? I wanted to but couldn't do it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like you should put the query (`...objects.get(user_assigned=pk)`) inside the `get_object` method.

To redirect to `account_add`, you can wrap the dispatch method like this:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  try:
    return super(AccountModify, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  except Employee.DoesNotExist:
    return redirect('account_add')
```

Comment: I tried, but if it comes up blank it get_object can not return a HTTP response object

Comment: Nice...is there any way I can have `return super(AccountModify, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` pass in the modified `queryset` so `def get_object()` gets it?

Comment: In my code there is no queryset, so there is nothing to pass. The idea is you do all the querying inside the `get_object` method. But you can override `get_queryset` if you need to for some reason.